# Jenkins: Parallel Deploy over SSH in the same server

Tags: jenkins, ssh, deployment

I am having two jenkins pipelines, frontend and backend. I am using deploy over ssh plugin to deploy the code in the server. Both the deployments are done in the same server. But I cannot do parallel deployments for both pipelines. When I do so One of the pipeline fails. Is there any other way to do parallel deployments on the same server?

Comment: What error are you getting ? It feels like maybe your deploy scripts cannot be run concurrently...